# Multiple YouTube players, in a tabbed angular-ui control. Want to add collapse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I guess my question is two parts:
1. Since I am new to angular and have never used the YouTube JavaScript API, I am sure that I am doing a bunch of things wrong. I wouldn't know because the code works, but I was wondering if some of the more experienced angular / javascript programmers here can let me know if they spot any issues with my code. Anything glaringly wrong, I am totally open to criticism so I can learn and feel free to send me a message directly if you feel uncomfortable answering here.

Now, before my question gets downvoted and closed, I do have a legitimate issue to solve! :)

In the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bo3F9x0lDf4SWnDbShgL?p=preview) here you will find a small subset of my website. I am trying to get a tabbed youtube player that plays videos that I pre-select. just some dog protection videos right now. Anyway, I have two issues and wanted to get advice on one of them:

I want to add a [collapse](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) button to the entire div. What I was hoping to achieve is that the youtube players will not load when the page loads but rather when the div is uncollapsed to speed up page load. But I can't seem to get how to do that (make something happen when collapse is false). Hopefully someone has done something like this before. In the plunker, it's actually not properly uncollapsing the div when you click the button but it seems to work properly in my environment so not sure what gives but regardless hopefully the code is enough for someone to suggest things on.

Any advice will be much appreciated, and of course I can supply more information if needed. Feel free to completely change the way I code things, assume I know nothing which is partially true :)

Thanks!

Comment: Collapsing didn't work for me in your plunker.You are using collapse as a directive which is not defined. Try this. <div class="span12" ng-init="collapse=isCollapsed"> ..to initiate 'collapse'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can wrap the content of your tab's with

```
<tab><div ng-if="!isCollapsed">...tab-content...</div></tab>
```

to avoid initial loading. ng-if exists from AngularJS 1.1.5 upwards...

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXHc0z47RSymyYu3LLgA?p=preview

Changed Angular to 1.1.5 and set the initial value of $scope.isCollapsed in the controller to true.